# PHPのforeachの結果一件もなかったらという条件分岐を 2 回実行しないようにするためには？

Tags: php

下記で、foreachの結果一件もなかったらh2タグ自体を非表示にしたいのですが、foreachの結果一件もなかったらという条件分岐を 2 回実行しないようにするにはどうすればよいですか？

```
<h2>タイトル<h2>
<?php
foreach ($Ary as $val):
  if ($val == 5 || ($val >= $s && $val <= $e)):
    echo 'あり';
  endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: if 文は一つなのだから、既に条件分岐も一つな気がします。 / "foreach の結果一件もなかったら" は、配列の要素に何もなければ、で合っていますか？

Comment: 「配列の要素に何もなければ」で合っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<H2>` タグの出力は配列の要素数で決まるのだから、`foreach` の前に判定可能なはずです。

**修正例:**

```php
<?php

if ( count($Ary) !== 0) {
    echo "<h2>タイトル<h2>";
}

foreach ($Ary as $val):
  if ($val == 5 || ($val >= $s && $val <= $e)):
    echo 'あり';
  endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

参考:
[PHP: count - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.count.php)